# How to extract text between quotations in R

Tags: regex, r

I have this string:

```
"MYDATA[, \"TYUO\"]"
```

How can I extract the text between the quotes? So the result is just `TYUO` ?

Comment: Something like `sub('.*"(.*)".*', "\\1", x)` maybe Or for nicer print `cat(sub('.*"(.*)".*', "\\1", x))`

Comment: Those are regex, no?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, can you post this as an answer since there's no base-R answer yet?

Comment: @BenBolker this assumes there's only one instance of the quoted substring within each string which very well may be the case for this poster.

Answer (score 9):

Using `stringi` with lookahead and lookbehind:

```
> stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(s, '(?<=").*?(?=")')
```

Answer (score 9):

**qdapRegex**'s (I coauthored this package with Jason Gray aka @hwnd) `rm_between` function is born for this:

```
x <- c("MYDATA[, \"TYUO\"]", 'a "second" with "multiple" quotes')

library(qdapRegex)
rm_between(x, '"', '"', extract=TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "TYUO"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "second"   "multiple"
```

**EDIT**

@BenBolker asked for a base R solution.  This is not as pretty as I had hoped but would get it done in base R:

```
lapply(regmatches(x, gregexpr('(\").*?(\")', x, perl = TRUE)), function(y) gsub("^\"|\"$", "", y))

## [[1]]
## [1] "TYUO"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "second"   "multiple"
```

I don't like stripping off the leading trailing quotes with an `lapply` `gsub` but to try use the standard lookahead/lookbehind the result is not what we want:

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?<=\")(.*?)(?=\")", x, perl = TRUE))

## [[1]]
## [1] "TYUO"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "second"   " with "   "multiple"
```