# How to extract text from a string using a regular expression in R?

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector of strings such as:

```
x <- c("gene_biotype \"protein_coding\"; transcript_name \"IGHV3-66-201\"; 
transcript_source \"havana\"; transcript_biotype \"IG_V_gene\"; 
protein_id \"ENSP00000375041\"; protein_version \"2\"; tag 
\"cds_end_NF\"; tag \"mRNA_end_NF\"; tag \"basic\"; 
transcript_support_level \"NA\";",
"gene_id \"ENSG00000211973\"; gene_version \"2\"; transcript_id 
\"ENST00000390633\"; transcript_version \"2\"; exon_number \"1\"; 
gene_name \"IGHV1-69\"; gene_source \"ensembl_havana\"; gene_biotype 
\"IG_V_gene\"; transcript_name \"IGHV1-69-201\"; transcript_source 
\"ensembl_havana\"; transcript_biotype \"IG_V_gene\"; protein_id 
\"ENSP00000375042\"; protein_version \"2\"; tag \"cds_end_NF\"; tag 
\"mRNA_end_NF\"; tag \"basic\"; transcript_support_level \"NA\";",
"gene_id \"ENSG00000211973\"; gene_version \"2\"; transcript_id 
\"ENST00000390633\"; transcript_version \"2\"; exon_number \"2\"; 
gene_name \"IGHV1-69\"; gene_source \"ensembl_havana\"; gene_biotype 
\"protein_coding\";")
```

I need to extract the quoted text (any characters) that follows gene_biotype. For example:

```
[1] protein_coding\ 
[2] IG_V_gene\
[3] protein_coding\
```

I have tried using str_extract in the stringr package, but I cannot get the regex to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with some help from the `stringr` package to get the data you need. For example

```
library(stringr)
str_match(x, "gene_biotype\\s+\"([^\"]+)\"")
#      [,1]                                [,2]            
# [1,] "gene_biotype \"protein_coding\""   "protein_coding"
# [2,] "gene_biotype \n\"IG_V_gene\""      "IG_V_gene"     
# [3,] "gene_biotype \n\"protein_coding\"" "protein_coding"
```

This returns a matrix with the match and the category. If you just want the category you can do

```
str_match(x, "gene_biotype\\s+\"([^\"]+)\"")[,2]
# [1] "protein_coding" "IG_V_gene"      "protein_coding"
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320081/how-to-extract-text-between-quotations-in-r)

```
stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(x, '(?<=").*?(?=")')[[1]][1]
#[1] "protein_coding"
```